# SharePoint list versions

Tags: infopath, version-history, version

We have a list that we turned SP versioning on it.  When someone makes a change, it records two records in the version list.  The first record shows the change field and the second one is just listing the version.

[image]

I change the form with Infopath so would that be a reason?

thanks, BJ

Answer (score 1):

Your version 6.0 shows the **Program** field being edited and the value 'test' being entered.

Version 7.0 shows that no values changed.  It's difficult to deduce what you did to trigger version 7.0 being made.

Test it - try making a minor change to the form again, using Infopath - does it make Version 8.0?  If it does make a v8.0 then yes, Infopath being changed created a new version.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out. I walked thru the process and in my info path I have an update to hold a value and then I have an update again after my check.  So that is why it has two version per change.  (Hit head against wall) :)